# "pulumi import" not working for GCP resources while import operation

Tags: typescript, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, pulumi

I'm using **Pulumi-Typescript** to deploy infrastructure in GCP.

I have 1 Google Kubernetes Engine resource already deployed in my project.
To use that existing resource in Pulumi operation, I found documentation on pulumi import in which I explored about how it actually works.
By referring that document, I have added Import configuration are as follow:

```
import * as gcp from "@pulumi/gcp";
import * as pulumi from "@pulumi/pulumi";
import * as k8s from "@pulumi/kubernetes";
import * as infraJson from "../parameters/infrastructure-parameters.json"

export const gke = new gcp.container.Cluster(infraJson.clusterConfigs.CLUSTER_NAME,
  {
    name: infraJson.clusterConfigs.CLUSTER_NAME,
    initialNodeCount: infraJson.clusterConfigs.CLUSTER_DEFAULT_NODEPOOL_NODE_COUNT,
    removeDefaultNodePool: false,
    location: infraJson.clusterConfigs.RESOURCE_LOCATION,
    nodeConfig: {
      preemptible: false,
      machineType: infraJson.clusterConfigs.CLUSTER_MACHINE_TYPE,
      oauthScopes: [
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/service.management.readonly",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring.write",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/servicecontrol",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/trace.append"
      ]
    }
  }, {
     import: "projects/myproject/locations/us-central1-c/clusters/test-cluster"
  });
```

But, When I run command "**Pulumi up**" it shows me warning:

```
gcp:container:Cluster (test-cluster):
    warning: previously-imported resources that still specify an ID may not be replaced; please remove the `import` declaration from your program.
```

I searched everywhere about how to do it in GCP, but not found anything.

If anyone knows how to do it, Please help me with this issue..!
Thank you...!

Comment: And what happens if you remove the 'import' line and run ```pulumi up``` again?

Comment: If I removed "Import" theen it will be run like we're creaing new cluster

Comment: I know this isn't a solution, but since this error is not mentioned on Pulumi website, I would suggest deploying everything anew with Pulumi and removing the old cluster.

Comment: @Sergiusz If we want to change small configuration then for that replacing the whole infrastructure is not the standard practice.

Answer (score 2):

The only place in the Pulumi code base containing that warning is here:

https://github.com/pulumi/pulumi/blob/272c4643b20d40113689475fd2f9fe3134e6d431/pkg/resource/deploy/step_generator.go#L540-L551

What I understand from this code is this: you specified an ID of an existing cluster to import, as part of Pulumi code describing to "to be" situation of your cluster. But your existing cluster configuration differs from the description of your cluster config in the code. This leads to Pulumi wanting to to replace your cluster, but it is prevented by your `import` option, hence the warning.

Please run `pulumi preview --diff` and see where the config in your code differs from the actual state. Change your code to match the actual state. At that moment, `pulumi preview` should tell you there are no changes. Once you have that, you should be able to run `pulumi up` without a problem.

Comment: First of all, I checked all the cluster configuration. which is all accurate and there is no change made by me in code. if I run ```pulumi preview --diff``` then if shows change of URN and ID's and some information regarding kubeconfig file.
Second thing is, As per the import command used for importing GCP resources I give the exact way. so it has to be import. but due to the automatic change in URN and ID it is going to replace. Which I think it is completly wrong.

Comment: @KaivalyaDambalkar can you post the output of the preview command? I would like to see what is different on the URN.